# Keep Line Breaks from Textarea

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am getting input from a user in a form via PHP in a WordPress site (an address specifically) and I want to be able to display the information that I gather with the same line breaks (separating out the different components of the address) on a different page.  It displays correctly if I put it into a textarea, but if I get the data and echo it into a div by itself, it doesn't maintain the line breaks.  What can I do?

Comment: [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) ?

Comment: lol you are amazing - I'm such a n00b at PHP but we all have to learn sometime!

Answer (score 23):

you want to utilize the white-space css attribute http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

So you'll have something like

```
<p class="whitespace"><?= $input_from_textarea ?></p>
```

with css:

```
.whitespace { 
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
}
```

Do not manually clean your input replacing new line elements with break tags. It makes your data less reusable and is a lot more work.

You can use the php function `nl2br()` but it does not give you as much control as manipulating the display through css.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `echo nl2br( $string)` to convert `\n` to `<br>` HTML line break.

Answer (score 2):

HTML collapses any amount of whitespace (except non breaking space) including new lines to a single space. In order to maintain new lines, you will need to replace new lines with `<br>` or use `<pre>` tags or use one of the [white-space CSS rules designed to control this behaviour.](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/)

Answer (score 2):

use nl2br() method to ratain your . nl2br($text); 
for more quires check this
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `<pre>` tag for example. But it will look quite ugly.

Or replace line breaks with `<br/>`